# How to disable profile images?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-2

In lower level public matchmaking games (on the Stockholm server) I'm often paired with players using Hitler, Mussolini and [Anders Behring Breivik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Behring_Breivik) facial photographs as profile images, among other fascist leaders and terrorists. This is not an exaggeration and is based on over 1000 hours of playtime.

[Also major streamers are unable to play in official matchmaking due to graphic imagery](https://web.archive.org/web/20171017193640/https://clips.twitch.tv/StormyHotBatHotPokket) (**WARNING** - an offensive picture).

There is "mini-scoreboard style" option in game settings to hide the images during gameplay, but the photos are displayed at least when you are killed, spectating and inspecting scoreboard.

Comment: All I could find was that you can disable freezecam using: 
cl_disablefreezecam "1" and 
cl_freezecampanel_position_dynamic "0" this however might not always fully work

Comment: @KevinTheGreat: `cl_disablefreezecam` doesn't affect profile images, I've used the command since the beginning. `cl_freezecampanel_position_dynamic` affects the panel position.

Comment: There are several steps to disable certain features showing avatars one by one, but you can not disable them completely.

Comment: @dly: Are you aware of some additional commands?

Comment: You could try blocking the CDNs on which the images are stored. However, this might have side effects on other Steam content e.g. screenshots also being blocked.

Comment: @Mark: I'm experimenting with blocking `cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com` domain. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in competitive, while it does in casual modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Six years later and with Counter-Strike 2 replacing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive a user grumd on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/16k4sl5/comment/kctuefb/) says:

> `cl_hide_avatar_images 1` for those who were looking to just disable user avatars overall

---

[CS2 documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_Counter-Strike_2_console_commands_and_variables):

> | Name | Value | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | cl_hide_avatar_images | 0 | cl, a | Hide avatar images for other players. 0 - Off. 1 - Block All 2 - Block all but friends |

[the respective page for Global Offensive](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_console_commands_and_variables)

Answer (score 6):

Profile images *should be* hidden by blocking the domain(s) these images are loaded from. Add a string `0.0.0.0 cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com` ([use `127.0.0.1` if `0.0.0.0` doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)) to your operating system's [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), on Windows located in `~\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (for OS X and Linux see [How-To Geek's guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)). Unfortunately this also prevents some images on Steam store from loading and might have other side effects - it is recommended to comment out (or delete) the lines after playing by using `//` prefix on Windows (`#` [seems to be the Unix alternative](https://www.howtogeek.com/118389/how-to-comment-out-and-uncomment-lines-in-a-configuration-file/)):

```
//0.0.0.0 cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com
```

For unknown reasons (on my system, may not affect everyone) profile images are blocked from loading in "deathmatch", "arms race", "demolition" and "casual" modes, but **not in "competitive"**. However, it's possible that there are additional locations for profile mages which I'm not aware of.

---

**This not a proper solution and will stop working if Valve moves profile images to another location**. The game can also  load all data from the same domain in the future, making blocking impossible without completely cutting internet access. Only Valve can effectively solve this issue, by implementing a  setting to hide Steam profile images.

Comment: `cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com` (`cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/`) seems to also be used, I will test later.

Comment: blocking `cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com` had seemingly no impact in the game.

Comment: I should have recommended blocking at the DNS level. See the more recent answer for the console command `cl_hide_avatar_images`.